# Online capacity expansion of RAID10 on PERC H830 Unavailable

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc, raid10

Per updates notes on Firmware ver 25.3.0.0016 ([link](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=WN0HC)), the PERC H830 now supports online capacity expansion (OCE) of RAID10 volumes with less than 32 disks.  Our card is at firmware 25.5.x.

We have two disk groups with two vdisks - one per disk group.  The vdisk in question is a RAID10 with four (4) 12TB SATA drives.  I'm trying to do an OCE of this disk with four more 12TB disks.  The drives show up as "Ready" in the PERC but there is no "Reconfigure..." option available in OpenManage or in the controller BIOS.  The ability to do this is also referenced in the users guide ([link](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/poweredge-rc-h330_users-guide_en-us.pdf)).

Here's a look at what I'm seeing in the BIOS:

[image]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Online Capacity Expansion must be performed within OMSA (OpenManage), which needs to be installed within the host OS. This cannot be done from the PERC BIOS.

Comment: The MegaRaid CLI tools can do this as well if you don't want the overhead of OMSA.

Comment: Note my comment in the original question, that the "Reconfigure" option is not present in OpenManage either.